# Android Studio is not including the .so library in the apk:

Tags: android, c++, string, android-ndk

I am calling the native method this way:

```
public native String callTest(String mCurrentPhotoPath);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("jni_part");
}
```

And this is my cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const char* toGray(const char* path){
    IplImage* img = NULL;
    if ((img = cvLoadImage(path))== 0){
        printf("cvLoadImage failed\n");
    }
    return path;
}

extern "C" {

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_MainActivity_callTest(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jstring param) {
    const char* path = env->GetStringUTFChars(param, 0);
    return env->NewStringUTF(toGray(path));
}

}
```

I've tried the toGray to be before and after extern "C"(when it was after i first declared it before extern "C" and then set its functionality below).
Crash error:

```
03-05 15:12:37.930  13775-13775/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jni_part from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:359)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
            at com.example.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:56)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include /home/radibg2/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni//OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := jni_part
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace or other logging information about your crash.

Comment: What is the exact name of your `.so` library? It should be `libjni_part.so`.

Comment: Its name is libjni_part.so

Comment: It's not being found in your .apk.  Open the .akp with a zip utility have have a look for it.

Comment: If you are using the NDK build options for shared runtime support, you need to load the shared runtime support libraries before your library. Android does not support "cascade" loading of shared libraries.

Comment: In the lib folder there is only libapp.so, no libjni_part.so

Comment: So where did libapp.so come from? If your are building with ndk-build post the relevant parts of your .mk files.

Comment: Yes, i am building it with ndk, and what means "casecade" loading of shared libraries? I don't know, i will post the mk files in a second

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` and a picture of your IDE so I can see your folder structure(or post a picture of the command `tree`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the NDK was generating the libraries in libs folder, but they have to be in jniLibs folder.